# Is Package design Sonar analysis supported for .NET projects?

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to Sonar how ever I have some basic overview of its capabilities.

My problem is that the *Package design* and *File design* widgets don't show any data. 
Are these metrics supported on a C# analysis project or only Java code is supported ?..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be supported for C#, but it has been dropped in version 3.0 because it was badly supported.

See the following ticket: [SONARCS-38](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCS-38)